# Why does this query work in MySQL but fail in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This query works as intended in MySQL, but fails in MariaDB as not being able to recognize the "uID" field.
Why?  Is it possible to code one version for both?

```
select user_id as uID, last_name, first_name, athlete, parent, coach, code,
   sum(points) as total,
   propoints as lifetime,
   (select count(*) / 7 from 
        (select count(user_id), Date(created_at) as date
          from user_propoints
          where user_id = uID
          group by date) as ac1)
    as activity
from user_propoints
left join users on users.id = user_id
left join countries on users.country = countries.id
group by user_id
```

order by total desc

Output from MySQL:

21530   Mazzucchelli    Lou 0   0   0   NULL    37  37  0.5714

Output from MariaDB:

Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'uID' in 'where clause'

Comment: write a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org) requesting it be fixed.

Comment: It's a bit of an odd one. I am not sure that this is really a bug, as the innermost query is a derived table, and as such cannot be correlated (unless lateral).

Comment: But why is MySQL not complaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple tables in a query you should alias your tables and qualify the column names with the table aliases. As you have not provided the DDL for your tables, I have guessed and you can correct as required.

Your `left join`s should probably be `inner join`s, as `user_propoints` for a user that does not exist does not make sense. Similarly, as long as `users.country` does not allow nulls, it should be an `inner join`.

I think you are over-complicating your query with the correlated subquery. Surely, this should provide the desired result:

```sql
select
    up.user_id as uID, u.last_name, u.first_name, u.athlete, u.parent, u.coach,
    c.code,
    sum(up.points) as total,
    u.propoints as lifetime,
    count(distinct date(up.created_at)) / 7 as activity
from user_propoints up
join users u on u.id = up.user_id
join countries c on u.country = c.id
group by up.user_id;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0hPBugc4).

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id as uID, last_name, first_name, athlete, parent, coach, code,    sum(points) as total,    propoints as lifetime,    (select count(*) / 7 from 
        (select count(user_id), Date(created_at) AS DATE
          from user_propoints
          where user_id = user_propoints.user_id  -- Join the subquery using user_id
          group by date) as ac1)
    as activity from user_propoints left join users on users.id = user_id left join countries on users.country = countries.id group by user_id order by total desc;
```

In this modified query, I replaced 'where user_id = uID' with 'where user_id = user_propoints.user_id' in the subquery.

Comment: That parses, but it does not do what I intend.  Your version returns the SAME activity value for every value of user_id.  The intent is to have uID act as an outer loop (the outer SELECT) variable that will generate an activity value for each distinct instance of user_id.  Execute the original in MySQL to see the difference.